# CSS perspective-origin relative to window

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

I set `perspective-origin: 50% 50%` on the body and all elements that move along the Z axis are shown with perspective relative to the height of the document. I would like to set perspective origin to the middle of my browser window, in a way that it updates the point of view as I scroll vertically or horizontally.

Any ideas? Think I would have to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  perspective: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/Grilly86/pen/pvdGEm

Comment: Wow thanks! Now I'm going to stare at this for a while and figure out how it works.